# how to stop name mangling in Qt class?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, ctypes, calling-convention

ultimately my goal is to write a Qt class(my class inherits from `QObject` and uses `Q_OBJECT` macro), then build a dll from it. then in python use ctype to access that dll.

when I write the dll normally, method names get mangled so I can't use them directly. instead I have to use `getattr` which I don't want to use(because others may need to use the dll and I don't want them to get confused).

anyway I read that to stop name mangle I need to use `extern "C"`

so far I tried these:

```
extern "C"
{
   class MyClass::public QObject
   {
       Q_OBJECT

   public:
       void SomeFunction(int Parameter);
   }
}
```

this one does not build because in Q_OBJECT macro templates are used and I get "templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage" error.

i tried:

```
extern "C" typedef void SomeFunction_t(int parameter);

class MyClass::public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   SomeFunction_t SomeFunction;
}
```

this one compiled but still `SomeFunction` name was mangled;

also I can't use `extern "C"` directly before method declaration because it is inside of class.
so how can I prevent name mangling here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess this might be failing because of this construct:

```cpp
extern "C"
{
  class I_AM_A_CPLUSPLUS_CONCEPT {};
}
```

Anyhow, this is solvable, but requires a little rethink. To expose the class to C, you will have to jump through a couple of hoops here.

```cpp
   // the C++
   class MyClass : public QObject
   {
       Q_OBJECT

   public:
       void SomeFunction(int Parameter);
   };

   extern "C" MyClass* MyClass_new() {
       return new MyClass;
   }

   extern "C" void MyClass_delete(MyClass* c) {
       delete c;
   }

   extern "C" void MyClass_SomeFunction(MyClass* c, int p) {
       c->SomeFunction(p);
   }
```

'MyClass' will be mangled into a C++ name, and there isn't really any way to expose 'SomeFunction' as a member of MyClass, without using name mangling.

C-Name mangling in the above example will simply expose:

`MyClass_new`, `MyClass_delete`, and `MyClass_SomeFunction` as the symbol names. *(i.e. devoid of the function argument types, return type, calling convention, owning class, etc...  which is what C++ name mangling will add in)*.

Just treat MyClass as an opaque pointer, and C code should be happy enough with that. Short of resorting to pybind/boost::python *(which clearly don't really work with DLL's cleanly!!)*, there aren't really any other nice ways to bind in a C++ object to c code.